# How many different subsets $Y \subset X$ with $|Y| \leq n$ are there if $|X| = 2n+1$? (Elegant solution?)

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

I've been given the above task, and I was quite surprised about how easy it seemed.

### My solution

$$N = \binom{2n+1}{0} + \binom{2n+1}{1} + \ldots + \binom{2n+1}{n} = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{i}$$

Basically, you count how many subsets you can form with exactly zero elements, with one element, etc., all the way to the amount of subsets with exactly $n$ elements.

### The question

Sums are one thing of course. But the fact that the task was asked not for sets $X$ of any size, but for ones with exactly $2n + 1$ elements makes me wonder whether there is a more elegant solution to this problem.

Is there, and if yes, how do you find it?

Comment: Hint: $|Y|>n$ iff $|X\setminus Y|\leq n$.

Comment: While it is basically the same solution, the $k^{th}$ row of Pascal's triangle sums to $2^{k+1}$. You are counting half of these.

Comment: Even if you didn't see the "elegant" solution offhand, didn't you notice the pattern $1,4,16,64,\dots$ when you worked out the first few values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every subset $A\subseteq X$ list $A$ if $|A|\leq n$ and list $A^{\complement}$ otherwise.

Then we have a list of $2^{2n+1}$ subsets.

All sets that have cardinality $\leq n$ are on that list and every set on it is listed twice.

So there are $\frac12\cdot2^{2n+1}=2^{2n} $ subsets with cardinality $\leq n$.

Comment: I see that this is quite an elegant solution. May you clarify what the $A^C$ notation means, and how this leads to us having counted every subset exactly twice?

Comment: $A^{\complement}:=X\setminus A$. If e.g. $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ then for set $\{1\}$ we put $\{1\}$ itself in the list. But for set $\{2,3,4,5\}$ (the complement of set $\{1\}$) we *again* put $\{1\}$ in the list. So this set will land twice in the list. This is true for all sets that end in the list.

Comment: @StckXchnge-nub12 $A^\complement$ is the complement of $A$: $X \setminus A$. A set has size $\le n$ or its complement (its non-elements) has size $\le n$ and exactly one of them has to occur